# Convert XML to JSON in Python using lxml and XSLT

Tags: python, json, xml, xslt, lxml

I am transforming XML to JSON using python3, lxml-library, and XSLT. I keep getting `XSLTParseError` when running my code and I am not sure how to proceed forward.

**Sample XML Message:**

```
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns0:BookStore xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com/xsd/books">
         <ns0:Book>
            <ns0:Title>The Power of Now</ns0:Title>
            <ns0:Author>Vivek Ranadive</ns0:Author>
            <ns0:Date>1999</ns0:Date>
            <ns0:ISBN>0-06-566778-9</ns0:ISBN>
            <ns0:Publisher>Tibco Software Inc</ns0:Publisher>
         </ns0:Book>
      </ns0:BookStore>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Expected JSON Outcome:**

```
  "Envelope": {
    "Body": {
      "BookStore": {
        "Book": {
          "Title": "The Power of Now",
          "Author": "Vivek Ranadive",
          "Date": 1999,
          "ISBN": "0-06-566778-9",
          "Publisher": "Tibco Software Inc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[XSLT being used](https://github.com/bramstein/xsltjson/blob/master/conf/xml-to-json.xsl)

**Python Code:**

```
dom = ET.parse('XML_Example01.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('XSLT.xsl')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(newdom)
```

**Error I get:**
`XSLTParseError: xsl:when : could not compile test expression 'normalize-space(.) ne . or not((string(.) castable as xs:integer  and not(starts-with(string(.),'+')) and not(starts-with(string(.),'0') and not(. = '0'))) or (string(.) castable as xs:decimal  and not(starts-with(string(.),'+')) and not(starts-with(.,'-.')) and not(starts-with(.,'.')) and not(starts-with(.,'-0') and not(starts-with(.,'-0.'))) and not(ends-with(.,'.')) and not(starts-with(.,'0') and not(starts-with(.,'0.'))) )) and not(. = 'false') and not(. = 'true') and not(. = 'null')'`

My main reasoning for using XSLT is to eventually add logic to perform force-array, this way  the converted JSON file has consistent arrays. Also, the sample XML is just a generic XML, the actual files a bit complex and bigger with lots of nestings.

I **do not** get the same error if I use the same XML and XSLT in XML Spy to perform the conversion.

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: `lxml` supports only XSLT 1.0. However, if you have an [external XSLT 2.0 processor](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info), Python can make a command line call to it.

Comment: Furthermore, Saxon/C offers XSLT 3.0 and has a Python language binding.

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet requires an XSLT 2.0 processor. The `libxslt` processor used by `lxml` supports XSLT 1.0 only.